# Service sensio_distribution.webconfigurator no found

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

I work on a Symfony2.4 project and I decided to go into production environment but when emptying the cache production I got this error :

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent service
>   "sensio_distribution.webconfigurator".

I don't know when this service is used but I searched the file "webconfigurator.xml" and I have found the service called "sensio_distribution.webconfigurator"... 
The file path is the following :

> vendor/sensio/Bundle/DIstributionBundle/Resources/config/webconfigurator.xml

And this is the file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="sensio_distribution.webconfigurator.class">Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Configurator\Configurator</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="sensio_distribution.webconfigurator" class="%sensio_distribution.webconfigurator.class%">
            <argument>%kernel.root_dir%</argument>
        </service>

        <!-- deprecated, kept for BC -->
        <service id="sensio.distribution.webconfigurator" alias="sensio_distribution.webconfigurator" />
    </services>
</container>
```

So why do I have this error?

**EDIT:** the sensio distribution bundle is loaded in AppKernel.php

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('prod', 'dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }
```

Comment: The SensioDistributionBundle wasn't accidentally removed in AppKernel.php ?

Comment: No, the SensioDistributionBundle is loaded in AppKernel.php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found my mistake :**

I had to move my bundle Acme outside the "if" condition, removing "prod" in :

`if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('prod', 'dev', 'test')))`

and it works :)