# Clear Cache: You have requested a non-existent service "sensio_distribution.webconfigurator"

Tags: php, symfony

When run ***app/console cache:clear***, no problem. But when I try to clear prod cache (***app/console cache:clear --env prod***) I get:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException] You have requested a non-existent service "sensio_distribution.webconfigurator".
```

I dont have the first clue what am I doing wrong.

my config:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Propel
propel:
    dbal:
        #driver:   "%database_driver%"
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        dsn:      "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=symfony;charset=UTF-8%"

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

# FOS
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350469/service-sensio-distribution-webconfigurator-no-found

Comment: that solution did not work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove manually all directories under app/cache/